# Access to Outlook Intergration

Tags: ms-access, outlook

I would like to ask if email address in an MS Access DB can be imported into MS Outlook (preferably in contact groups defined in MS Access)? If so, how can this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Review https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/update-outlook-contact-item-using-vba.1839879/ and https://www.devhut.net/2010/09/03/vba-create-an-outlook-contact/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

I have a list of contact details (email address, name, organizations, telephone number, etc) on a excel file which I intend to do a import into Access via CSV. I would like to see if I can provide a direct link of this eventual contact details database directly to Outlook's Address book.

The provided links seem to be a entry by entry solution which could be time exhausting for the number of records I have.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to export a CSV from Outlook into Access, or from Access into Outlook?  How's Excel involved?  Are you importing from Excel to Access to Outlook? (if, so, why, and where is the data coming from before that?)

Comment: I have a list of contact information in MS Excel, which was already provided. Which I am tasked to import into an MS Access DB.

These contact information, which includes emails, are already used for sending email to these recipients but are maintained in MS Excel.

I am tasked to convert it into a Access DB.

I was looking for a way to link this information, which will be in Access DB, to Outlook. Ideally maintain a link such that future updates in Access will also be reflected into Outlook's Address Book.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to work with outlook items in Access, is through linked tables. Access can directly link to your outlook files.

Steps (Access 2016):

- Go to External Data
- Click New Data Source
- Click form other sources
- Choose Outlook folder
- Choose Link the data source by creating a linked table
- Choose the address book you want to link
- Click Finish

You now have a linked outlook address book as a table. You can use normal action queries to insert into and update your address book.

Comment: Linked Table on works for contact data already present in Outlook address book, but I have external data from another source. Would you recommend importing it into Outlook first before linking it to a linked table into Access?

Comment: You can just use an insert query to insert new data into the linked table. I don't see why you would import it using something else first. That usually includes both exporting from Access and importing into outlook, and is hard to automate. A properly written action query can usually do it in one go

Comment: My created linked table from the above mentioned steps are always empty, is it supposed to be the case?

Comment: It should contain the address book you're linking it to. If the address book is empty, your linked table is empty. Note you can both link to address books, and contact lists associated with mail accounts.

Comment: Does a corporate address book affect this?

Comment: That depends how it's set up.

Comment: I am getting this error when I am trying to edit the Linked Table:

Microsoft Access error – You do not have the necessary permissions to use the...

Although I saw that it happens with older versions of Access, but I am using Access 2016.

Comment: That sounds like you lack permissions on a shared list. Make sure you get them

Comment: I am trying it on my PC, how can I set the permissions to do it?

Answer (score 0):

### To import a CSV of contacts into Outlook,

- click `File` then `Open & Export`
- click `Import/Export` and `Import from another program or file`
- click `Browse` and locate your **.csv** file

You'll have the option to map custom fields -- in case you don't have them stored in a standard way (like [this sample](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/2/5B2108F8-112B-4913-A761-38AFF2FD8598/Sample%20CSV%20file%20for%20importing%20contacts.csv])).

**More:**

- [Import contacts Excel→Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-contacts-from-an-Excel-spreadsheet-to-Outlook-f6483469-0684-4c30-82c5-c881930f5451)
- [Outlook & CSV's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-edit-csv-files-to-import-into-Outlook-4518d70d-8fe9-46ad-94fa-1494247193c7)
- [Adding a contact with VBA](https://www.devhut.net/2010/09/03/vba-create-an-outlook-contact/)

Comment: If the contact information is being updated in the future, would that mean if I have to re-import into Outlook using an updated .csv file?

Comment: Tan Yong Jin Stark yes if you import contact details from a CSV file.  Each .CSV file would be the details at the point in time the file is created.  So if details are changed, the .CSV file exported would not be updated.